# rails paramsで受け取った

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### radio_button_tagから選択されたデータをparamsで受け取って表示viewで表示させたい

下記の画像とコードを見ていただくととくにエラーは出ていないのですがresultviewにはradio_buttonから受け取ったはずの値が表示されていません、解決策がわからずどうしたらいいのかわからないのでご教授いただけると幸いです。
[image: selectbiewのページ]
**selectview**

```
<%= form_with url: "/home/result", controller: 'home', action: 'result', local: true do %>
    <section >質問1
      <p>  
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question1","1")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question1_1","1")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question1","2")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question1_2","2")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("@Question1","3")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question1_3","3")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question1","4")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question1_4","4")%>
      </p>  
    </section>
    <section >質問2
      <p>  
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question2","1")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question_1","1")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question2","2")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question2_2","2")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question2","3")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question2_3","3")%>
        <%= radio_button_tag("Question2","4")%>
        <%= label_tag("Question2_4","4")%>
      </p>


    <%=submit_tag ("送信") %>


<%end%>
```

**controller**

```
def result
 case params[:Question1]
   when 1
     @Q1 = 1
   when 2
     @Q1 = 2
   when 3
     @Q1 = 3
   when 4
     @Q1 = 3
   else
     puts "質問１の回答がありません。"
 end
 case params[:Question2]
 when 1
   @Q2 = 1
 when 2
   @Q2 = 2
 when 3
   @Q2 = 3
 when 4
   @Q2 = 3
 else
   puts "質問2の回答がありません。"
 end
end
resultview
 <div class ="a">
 <h1>これが診断結果です</h1>
 <%= @Q1 %>
 <%= @Q2 %>
</div>
```

[image: resultviewのページ]

Answer (score 0):

再現したところparams内のキーがシンボルではなく文字列だったので、そちらで取得すると良さそうです。また、そのままだとvalueの値も文字列になるので `to_i` で数値に変換しています

```
  def result
    # 確認用
    # p params

    case1 = params["Question1"] ? params["Question1"].to_i : nil
    case2 = params["Question2"] ? params["Question2"].to_i : nil
    case case1
    when 1
      @Q1 = 1
    when 2
      @Q1 = 2
    when 3
      @Q1 = 3
    when 4
      @Q1 = 3
    else
      puts "質問1の回答がありません。"
    end

    case case2
    when 1
      @Q2 = 1
    when 2
      @Q2 = 2
    when 3
      @Q2 = 3
    when 4
      @Q2 = 3
    else
      puts "質問2の回答がありません。"
    end
  end
```